# How to create /etc/krb5.conf on EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, kerberos

I was following a guide on connecting to Kafka from EC2 instance and one of the steps was to check if '/etc/krb5.conf' exists on my EC2.

On my EC2 instance it only exists folder '/etc/krb5.conf.d' but not '/etc/krb5.conf'. From internal discussion with several people - they believe it should exist by default. Not sure why my instance do not have it.

Should it exist by default once new EC2 (RHEL 7.3) is started? 
If not - how to create it manually?

Comment: Hi; If we've answered your question please mark it as such which will verify it to others in the community; otherwise please let us know if any.

Comment: I thought I saw the answer several days ago but not now - can you post again so that I can approve it? thanks.

Comment: Ok.  I just undeleted it.  If it doesn't work, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not sure why a /etc/krb5.conf doesn't exist by default on your new EC2 (RHEL 7.3), I will say on all instances of Linux I have ever seen that file exists as /etc/krb5.conf.  What I would do is simply copy /etc/krb5.conf.d to /etc/krb5.conf.  Please ensure that it is properly configured for your Kerberos realm - to do that see the MIT example [here](http://web.mit.edu/KERBEROS/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5.4/doc/krb5-admin/Sample-krb5_002econf-File.html).